# return 0 in select count when no record found

Tags: sql, database, oracle

i'm trying to get an id , and a count in same query result.
the problem is when the record doesn't exist , the count return null instead of 0

this is the query

```
 SELECT DISTINCT Id
,(
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM table1
    WHERE reference_id = 300000009798620
    )
FROM table1
WHERE reference_id = 300000009798620;
```

Comment: "when the record does not exist", do you mean the entire record for given ref_id or only the ID column in the row retrieved by ref_id?

Comment: Please describe how to get a column value of the record that doesn't exist.

Comment: if you select count (*) for a record that doesn't not exist , you will get 0 as a result  , instead of null

Comment: Yes, you'll have 0 as a result. But in the question you state the opposite: *the problem is when the record doesn't exist , the count return null instead of 0*. This is confusing

Comment: yes it is returning as null , because i'm selecting other column with it , not the count itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use:

```
SELECT max(id) as id, count(*)
FROM table1
WHERE reference_id = 300000009798620
```

Comment: but if the count > 0 , i still need to get the id

Comment: @osfar . . . This returns both the `id` and the count.

Comment: no it is not working ,
there another field called Id , this should be retrieved

Comment: @osfar . . . I see.  `reference_id` is not the id you want.

Comment: @osfar - sorry, but what you are saying makes no sense. If there are no rows where the `reference_id` is the value you use in the query, then **what** `id` do you still need to return? There is no such `id` if there is no row in the table, where the `reference_id` is the one you give as input.

Comment: we have 2 cases here , if the record exist then the result would be
Id    , Count
22         1

but if the id doesn't not exist , then the result is 
Id     , Count

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below modified query

```
SELECT 300000009798620 as reference_id, count(*)
FROM table1 WHERE reference_id = 300000009798620
```

Comment: but if the count > 0 , i still need to get the id

Answer (score 0):

Would this do?

- `table1` CTE represents your table; I simplified `REFERENCE_ID`. Both rows share the same `reference_id` value (`1`), with two different `ID` column values (`1` and `2`)
- `temp1` selects `ID`s for `par_reference_id` parameter value
- `temp2` counts rows for `par_reference_id`

First execution returns *something* as `par_reference_id = 1` (count is `2`):

```
SQL> with
  2  table1 (id, reference_id) as
  3    -- this represents your TABLE1 (but reference_id is way simpler)
  4    (select 1, 1 from dual union all
  5     select 2, 1 from dual),
  6  temp_1 as
  7    -- distinct IDs per desired reference_id
  8    (select distinct id
  9     from table1
 10     where reference_id = &&par_reference_id
 11    ),
 12  temp_2 as
 13    -- number of rows for that reference_id
 14    (select count(*) cnt
 15     from table1
 16     where reference_id = &&par_reference_id
 17    )
 18  -- and finally:
 19  select b.id, a.cnt
 20  from temp_2 a left join temp_1 b on 1 = 1;
Enter value for par_reference_id: 1

        ID        CNT
---------- ----------
         1          2
         2          2
```

Let's try some other `reference_id` value (which doesn't exist in `table1`), e.g. `100`: query doesn't return any `ID`, but `count = 0` (as you wanted):

```
SQL> undefine par_reference_id
SQL> /
Enter value for par_reference_id: 100

        ID        CNT
---------- ----------
                    0

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DUAL` to always get a row back with your ID, then a subquery to get the count.

```sql
SELECT 300000009798620                            AS id,
       (SELECT COUNT (*)
          FROM table1
         WHERE reference_id = 300000009798620)    AS amt
  FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Inner query will also return a row without `dual` as it has the aggregate function without `group by`